# old blue navigation bar in bing v7 ajax control

Tags: jquery, ajax, bing-maps

I need to customize the navigation bar in my embedded bing map.

I am using the new Microsoft.Maps.Map V7 ajax but I was asked to restore the V6 VE Map style navigation bar to it while still using the V7 controls. Is this at all possible? Any advice?

Example: 
see in the interactive SDK:

- V6 with blue translucent bar: http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/ajax/
- V7 with new grey navigation bar: http://www.bingmapsportal.com/isdk/ajaxv7#CreateMap1

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot easily change the style of the built-in v7 navigation bar - it's not designed to be customised, doesn't have appropriate id/classes assigned to elements, and the structure is liable to change without warning between releases.

Instead, the most reliable option is to disable the built-in v7 navigation bar completely (by initialising the map with showDashboard: false), and then construct your own navbar div that mimics the style of the v6 dashboard and place this on top of the map using CSS positioning.

Comment: Yeah this is probably the cleanest approach

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible without some DOM/CSS hacks.  I would approach this by looking at the generated HTML of the V7 nav bar and try to re-style it to look like the V6 version while leaving all the functionality alone.

However, if the reason for this change request is due to the plain look/feel of the V7 nav bar, perhaps you can show them the snappier nav bar in the Bing Theme Module on the V7 maps and see if they will be satisfied with that instead?

http://www.bingmapsportal.com/isdk/ajaxv7#BingThemeModule1